# Someone who denies talking about something but then indirectly drops hints

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, descriptive-grammar

For example, someone had said something to me, obviously meaning something but then right after said that they weren't talking about that but then preceded to indirectly reference it, hint at it or beat around the bush. Basically saying it without saying it.

Is there a term for that?

Comment: In the New York area, we call that BS. That is, we call that BS "Subtle as a Mack truck."

Comment: The other thread contains many partial synonyms, such as **doublespeak** (Deliberately euphemistic, _ambiguous_, or obscure language [Lexico] ), _disingenuous_, and _dissembling_. Possibly _duplistic_.

Answer (score 0):

A  needler would delight in beating around the bush.

**needler**

> A person who goads, irritates, or torments others, esp. with the
> intention of provoking a reaction. OED

---

> Your objective is to force the **Needler** to come out of
> hiding and be open with the criticism. Get right to the point and
> needle the **Needler**. [A. C. Hakim and M. Solomon; *Working with
> Difficult People*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Working_with_Difficult_People/uxxyDQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=needler)